# Go RoundTrip/Transport Proxy Address

Tags: go, httpserver, http-proxy

I understand that the Proxy field of http.Transport asks for a function that generates proxy server addresses. So this is my roundtripper:

```
roundtripper := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: proxyrouter.Calculateproxy,
...
}
```

So the type of Proxy is `func(*Request) (*url.URL, error)`. This gets linked to the server and is later on called with:

```
response := roundtripper.RoundTrip(request)
```

Which returns the response. Now is there any way to know what proxy address was used to get this response? (since my Calculateproxy function just takes random addresses)

Comment: You'll need to check the headers. However, I'm not sure whether they will be present as the transport layer is adding them into a private [extra header section](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go#L289). Dump the req resp headers anyway ? They might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the Proxy function add a header to record the proxy server used:

```
Transport{
    Proxy: func(req *Request) (*url.URL, error) {
        p, err := proxyrouter.Calculateproxy(req)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        req.Header.Set("X-Proxy-Addr", p.String())
        return req, nil
    },
}
```

The [`http.Response`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) has a reference to the originating request

```
proxy := resp.Request.Header.Get("X-Proxy-Addr")
```

Comment: Yea, I think thats the only way it would.. Though I'm quite concerned with security issues here.

Comment: @PieterjanLambein: There's not really any security issue. Proxies are already known by their address in the "by" field of the "Forwarded" header, or in the "Via" header, or just by the host recording the connecting address. If you're still concerned, use an opaque identifier that doesn't correlate to anything outside the execution of your program.